# Nonlinear PDE: regularity issues

Tags: partial-differential-equations, regularity-theory-of-pdes, elliptic-equations

I have this execrise I've been trying to solve

Let $B=\{x \in \mathbb R^n: |x|<1\},  \quad a: \mathbb R^n \rightarrow \mathbb R , \quad a\in C^\infty(\mathbb R^n) \cap L^\infty(\mathbb R^n) $

$$\begin{cases} 
 -\Delta u +a(\nabla u) = 1  & \text{in $B$} \\
 \partial_{\nu }u + u = 0 & \text{in $\partial B$}
\end{cases}
 $$

I've been able to show that the solution exists and it also belong to $H^2(B)$, the next point I'm trying to show is:

**Show that every solution  $u \in H^2 (B)$, is also   $C^\infty( \bar B) $**

In the solution of my professor the answer is:

Being **$a (\nabla u) − 1 \in L^\infty (B)$  we get that $\nabla u ∈ L^\infty (B)$**

Since $a \in C^\infty(B)$ and $ \nabla u \in H^1 (B;\mathbb R^n)$ we get $a(\nabla u) \in H^1(B)$

....

From now on is all clear to me, but how can I say that $\nabla u ∈ L^\infty (B)$ ??

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Use the Definition of your pde!

Comment: that's the point, I don't get how can I infer $\nabla u ∈ L^\infty (B)$ from $\Delta u ∈ L^\infty (B)$

Comment: The weak formulation of the problem doesn't contain the Laplacian, only the gradient (and the gradient of your test function). Does that help?

Comment: Ehm.... I still can't see it!

Comment: I don't follow the sentence with "we get that", either. For all we know, $a$ could be identically zero, in which case $a(\nabla u) - 1\in L^\infty$ is not telling us anything about $\nabla u$.

Comment: @soup I think they are saying that if $\Delta u$ is $L^\infty$ and $u$ is $H^2$ then $\nabla u$ is also $L^\infty$. That does sound a bit strong, though.

Comment: It's not just like that, $u$ is also the solution of that PDE!